# Chakra UI spacing not matching expected defaults for padding and margin

Tags: reactjs, emotion, chakra-ui, styled-system

I'm working on converting my app from [rebass](https://rebassjs.org/) to [chakra](https://chakra-ui.com/) and currently dealing with a component that needs `16px` padding on mobile, and `24px` padding on tablet/desktop. In my component I have `<Component px={[4, 6, 6]} />`

Looking at [this chart](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theme#spacing), I would expect to be able to use these numbers `4, 6` because I have confirmed the font-size is `16px`. However, the actual values I'm seeing are `32px` on mobile and `128px` for tablet/desktop. I think something might be up with my chakra setup because I'm even unable to use inbetween values like `3.5`, however I have had no problems with it so far.

My chakra setup is pretty simple at the moment because I'm early in the migration and I'm not messing with the default chakra values for the `space` key so I don't know what's causing these weird numbers.

```
const config: ThemeConfig = {
  initialColorMode: 'dark',
  useSystemColorMode: false,
}

const Button: ComponentStyleConfig = {
  baseStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  variants: {
    primary: {
      letterSpacing: '-0.19px',
      borderRadius: '30px',
      paddingLeft: '45px',
      paddingTop: '14px',
      paddingRight: '45px',
      paddingBottom: '14px',
      height: '56px',
      backgroundColor: colors.white,
      color: colors.black,
    },
  },
  // The default size and variant values
  defaultProps: {
    variant: 'primary',
  },
}

const theme = {
  colors,
  styles: globalStyles,
  components: {
    Button,
  },
}

export default extendTheme({ ...theme, config })
```

Comment: Voted to close. This was due to some internal specific styling that was overriding it. I created a repl and wasn't having issues, then found out what was happening